# Return a Pandas DataFrame as a data_table from a callback with Plotly Dash for Python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I would like to read a .csv file and return a groupby function as a callback to be displayed as a simple data table with "dash_table" library. @Lawliet's helpful answer shows how to do that with "dash_table_experiments" library. Here is where I’m stuck:

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

df = pd.read_csv(
        'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chriddyp/'
        'c78bf172206ce24f77d6363a2d754b59/raw/'
        'c353e8ef842413cae56ae3920b8fd78468aa4cb2/'
        'usa-agricultural-exports-2011.csv')

app = dash.Dash()
application = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id = 'datatable',        
    ),

    html.Div([
        html.Button(id='submit-button',                
                children='Submit'
    )
    ]),    

])

@app.callback(Output('datatable','data'),
            [Input('submit-button','n_clicks')],
                [State('submit-button','n_clicks')])

def update_datatable(n_clicks,csv_file):            
    if n_clicks:                            
        dfgb = df.groupby(['state']).sum()
        return dfgb.to_dict('rows')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=False, port=8080)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you are trying to register the callback `Output` component as a `DataTable`, all the required / mandatory attributes for the `DataTable` component should be updated in the callback and returned. In your code, you are updating just `DataTable.data` and not `DataTable.column`, one easy way is to return the whole `Datatable` component which is prepopulated with all the required attribute values.

Here is an example,

```
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
import dash_table_experiments as dt

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

#data to be loaded
data = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13],['Alex',100]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Mark'])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dt.DataTable(
            rows=df.to_dict('records'),
            columns=df.columns,
            row_selectable=True,
            filterable=True,
            sortable=True,
            selected_row_indices=list(df.index),  # all rows selected by default
            id='2'
     ),
    html.Button('Submit', id='button'),
    html.Div(id="div-1"),
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('div-1', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('button', 'n_clicks')])
def update_output(n_clicks):

    df_chart = df.groupby('Name').sum()

    return [
        dt.DataTable(
            rows=df_chart.to_dict('rows'),
            columns=df_chart.columns,
            row_selectable=True,
            filterable=True,
            sortable=True,
            selected_row_indices=list(df_chart.index),  # all rows selected by default
            id='3'
        )
    ]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Looks like `dash-table-experiments` is deprecated.

Edit 1: Here is one way of how it can be achieved using `dash_tables`

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table as dt
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

df = pd.read_csv(
        'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chriddyp/'
        'c78bf172206ce24f77d6363a2d754b59/raw/'
        'c353e8ef842413cae56ae3920b8fd78468aa4cb2/'
        'usa-agricultural-exports-2011.csv')

app = dash.Dash()
application = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    dt.DataTable(
        id = 'dt1', 
        columns =  [{"name": i, "id": i,} for i in (df.columns)],

    ),
    html.Div([
        html.Button(id='submit-button',                
                children='Submit'
        )
    ]),    

])

@app.callback(Output('dt1','data'),
            [Input('submit-button','n_clicks')],
                [State('submit-button','n_clicks')])

def update_datatable(n_clicks,csv_file):            
    if n_clicks:                            
        dfgb = df.groupby(['state']).sum()
        data_1 = df.to_dict('rows')
        return data_1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=False, port=8080)
```

Another way: return the whole `DataTable`

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table as dt
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

df = pd.read_csv(
        'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/chriddyp/'
        'c78bf172206ce24f77d6363a2d754b59/raw/'
        'c353e8ef842413cae56ae3920b8fd78468aa4cb2/'
        'usa-agricultural-exports-2011.csv')

app = dash.Dash()
application = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id="table1"),

    html.Div([
        html.Button(id='submit-button',                
                children='Submit'
    )
    ]),    

])

@app.callback(Output('table1','children'),
            [Input('submit-button','n_clicks')],
                [State('submit-button','n_clicks')])

def update_datatable(n_clicks,csv_file):            
    if n_clicks:                            
        dfgb = df.groupby(['state']).sum()
        data = df.to_dict('rows')
        columns =  [{"name": i, "id": i,} for i in (df.columns)]
        return dt.DataTable(data=data, columns=columns)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(debug=False, port=8080)
```

I referred to this example:
https://github.com/plotly/dash-table/blob/master/tests/cypress/dash/v_copy_paste.py#L33

Comment: Thanks @Lawliet. I'm sorry I wasn't more clear in my question, I've edited it, I'm trying to return the groupby table using "dash_table" not "dash_table_experiments". I suppose I can just use dash_table_experiments instead though, as your example shows.

Comment: Thanks @Lawliet! Your solution works for returning dfgb, you just forgot to return that from the callback in your example, should be: data = dfgb.to_dict('rows')

Comment: A quick (optional) follow up question :). Do you know how to give the datatable the ability to be copied to the clipboard when it's contents are highlighted with the mouse, then ctrl+C?

Comment: @sparrow Shift and mouse clicks (or Shift and arrows) will let you highlight and Ctlr+C will copy to clipboard. This functionality exist by default.

Comment: @Lawliet, i have a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60556896/how-to-return-a-datatable-updated-by-2-dropdowns-as-inputs-in-plotly-python, 
if you are free, please drop by and have a look, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You almost got it done just with minor modification in `update_datatable` it should work fine (not tested):

```
def update_datatable(n_clicks,csv_file):            
    if n_clicks:                            
        dfgb = df.groupby(['state']).sum()
        return html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(
                data=dfgb.to_dict('rows'),
                columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in dfgb.columns],
                style_header={'backgroundColor': "#FFD700",
                              'fontWeight': 'bold',
                              'textAlign': 'center',},
                style_table={'overflowX': 'scroll'},  
                style_cell={'minWidth': '180px', 'width': '180px',
                        'maxWidth': '180px','whiteSpace': 'normal'},                        
                         filtering=True,
                 row_selectable="multi",
                 n_fixed_rows=1),
               html.Hr()
        ])
```

Comment: Thanks! that works. A quick (optional) follow up question :). Do you know how to give the datatable the ability to be copied to the clipboard when it's contents are highlighted with the mouse, then ctrl+C?

Comment: @shivsn i have a similary question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60556896/how-to-return-a-datatable-updated-by-2-dropdowns-as-inputs-in-plotly-python, 
if you are free, please drop by and have a look, thank you.